# Ошибка идификации

Tags: c#

Ошибка

> Error 1   A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connString = "MyConnectionString";

    try
    {   
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
            {
                comm.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var strQuery = "INSERT INTO 123 (......)" + 
                               "VALUES (.....)";
                    comm.CommandText = strQuery;
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(".........);

                    // больше параметров ...
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем столько `using`? Когда можно одним обойтись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Локальная переменная `Exception e` называется так же как параметр `EventArgs e`.

```
...
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    throw;
}
...
```